# How do I get IP address from socket In Windows

Tags: c++, sockets

I have the DWORD socket in windows.  I need to know if it is a connection that goes out to the internet or if it is a local connection, to some form of localhost.  Is there a good way to get the address that the socket is connected to in windows from just the socket?  Or is there a better way to tell if the connection is local or not?

Comment: You've got to be careful with IPv6. You most likely didn't create the socket yourself (else you could remember what it connected to) so you're probably dealing with some socket created elsewhere. And since that's outside your control it could use IPv6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to call [`getpeername()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738533(v=vs.85).aspx). Using it is pretty basic, you pass a `sockaddr` pointer and a length and it fills in the data for you.

As far as determining if the connection is local, [`getaddrinfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738520(VS.85).aspx) can give you a list of all available local addresses. You would compare the result of `getpeername()` to the local address list.